# Export mask to polygon

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'm trying to get the polygon of the water in a area.
The first step it was ok: mask the water using the `fmask` method.
But I don't know how to export this mask to a polygon, I'll probably have to use the function `reduceToVectors`, but I couldn't use it the right way. Can someone help me?

```js
var polygon = ee.Geometry.Polygon([[
  [-119.33364769821117, 46.05123532178373],
  [-119.3233620672313, 45.869732769408905],
  [-119.04111088542663, 45.873079023065166],
  [-119.0396574679861, 46.045448840018565]]]);

var landsat8 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC8_L1T_TOA_FMASK");

var FMASK_WATER = 1;

var mosaic = landsat8
.filterBounds(polygon)
.filterDate('2016-08-01', '2016-08-30')
.mosaic();

var fmask = mosaic.select('fmask');
var waterMask = fmask.eq(FMASK_WATER);
var maskedMosaic = mosaic.updateMask(waterMask);

Map.addLayer(maskedMosaic, {}, 'mask');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line:

```js
var waterFeatCol = waterMask.reduceToVectors({geometry: polygon, scale: 30}).filterMetadata("label","equals",1)
```

**waterPol** variable is a *FeatureCollection*, so, it is composed by many features. If you want a single feature do:

```js
var waterFeat = ee.Feature(waterPol.union(100).first())
```

Comment: I'm lucky StackExchange doesn't score comment mentions xD